# Add lines of a list as prefixes in filenames

Tags: bash, text-processing

How can I add elements of a list as a prefix plus a "_" to filenames?

filenames:

```
aaa.gf
bbr.gf
cee.gf
```

list.txt:

```
pplo
125ss
35w2
```

wanted result:

```
pplo_aaa.gf
125ss_bbr.gf
35w2_cee.gf
```

All elements are on the same folder. All target files end in .gf. Lines of list.txt should correspond to filenames alphabetically sorted, as shown in the example.

Got stuck on:

```
for f in *.gf; do mv "$f"  LINE_"$f"; done
```

Don't know how to make LINE work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
mapfile -t list < list.txt

i=0
for f in *.gf; do 
  echo mv "$f" "${list[i++]}_$f"
done
```

Remove the `echo` once you are happy that it is doing the right thing.

Answer (score 5):

With POSIX `sh` syntax:

```
#! /bin/sh -
for f in *.gf; do
  IFS= read -r line <&3 || break
  mv -i -- "$f" "${line}_$f"
done 3< list.txt
```

Globbing (here `*.gf`) sorts the list of files lexically (as per the locale's collation order in modern and POSIX compliant shells).

Answer (score 1):

With the `paste(1)` utility (avoiding slow shell loops, and overall simpler):

```bsh
# example list of files:
ls > files

paste -d_ list files
```

If you need to a `mv`, then things are only slightly more complicated:

```bsh
paste -d_ list files | paste files - | xargs -n2 echo mv
```

Remove the `echo` when you're ready to go.

Since we don't use anything but

- [POSIX features of POSIX-required `paste`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/paste.html)
- [POSIX features of POSIX-required `xargs`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html)
- pipelines

The whole thing should be POSIX compliant, `sh`-compliant, and therefore extremely portable.

But my favorite part is how easy it is to put together on the fly, interactively, piece by piece.

Answer (score 0):

POSIX-compliant solution would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

i=0
for f in *.gf
do
    echo mv "$f"  "$(tail -n+$i list.txt | head -1)"_"$f"
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

Tested with bash, dash, mksh and yash.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU Parallel:

```
parallel mv {1} {2}_{1} ::::+ filenames list.txt
```

or:

```
parallel mv {1} {2}_{1} ::: * ::::+ list.txt
```